# “Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function” - justifiedGallery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm implementing justifiedGallery in my website. However, I keep getting `Uncaught TypeError`.
I've included the files like below:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/justifiedGallery.css" />

<script src="js/jquery.justifiedGallery.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#mygallery").justifiedGallery();
    });
</script>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Pull up your console, head to the Network tab and verify that the plugin JS loaded okay.

Comment: Yeah, all loaded correctly :S

Comment: Do you have an html element which fits the selector $("#mygallery") ?

Comment: So if you type `$.fn.justifiedGallery` into the console, what does it say?

Comment: If I do that, I get `undefined`.

Comment: do you have html element with id ```mygallery``` ?